# Google Chrome now removed #https-upgrades flag, how do you prevent upgrades?

Tags: google-chrome

I've been using Google Chrome for a while, but just a couple of days ago the **HTTPS Upgrades** dropdown menu disappeared from chrome://flags/httpsUpgrades and I couldn't find an alternative way to disable upgrades.

I'm typing from Google Chrome v. 123.0.6312.59 (64 bit)